# How do I authenticate for cloud functions when using the Firebase Local Emulator?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to set up the firebase local emulator to be able to test cloud functions. But I'm either getting "Error: Unauthenticated" responses outside the main function or auth errors within it, depending on whether or not I've tried to authenticate using the client SDK. The cloud function looks like this:

```js
export default functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {    
    console.log(context.auth)
    // Custom function code and authentication checks that rely on context.auth existing
}
```

And the attempts to call it look like this:

```js
await firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
})
await firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001')
//await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

//let res = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
const result = await firebase.functions().httpsCallable('myFunction')(data)
```

If I run it like this, I can see logging within the cloud function that shows the context argument has no auth values. If I uncomment the user sign-in stuff, I get an Error: Unauthenticated response and the function itself never gets run.

Is there some configuration stuff I'm missing for this? I haven't been able to find much documentation around using the emulator.

Comment: What version of firebase-tools are you using?

Comment: 7.1.0. I've also tried this using both nodes 8 and 10, no difference.

Comment: It's 2022 now and I have this exact problem. Every other emulated service works and everything works fine in prod. This must be a bug in firebase-tools. My user is authenticated and should have access.

Answer (score -1):

After digging deep into the actual SDK, I managed to figure it out. I was using a bad API key, meaning the generated token was bad. The correct way is to create the user and log in as the user before making the call.